# simple newsletter opt-in form php

Tags: php, html

I'm having a few issues on making an email newsletter opt-in form.

I have this html code in my site :

```
<form name="myform" method="post" action="http://site.domain/form.php">

<p><label>Emri: </label><input type="text" name="firstname"></p>

<p><label>Adresa e-mail: </label><input type="text" name="email"></p>

<p><input type="submit" name="Posto" value="Posto"></p>

</form>
```

And I used this as form.php :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $data = $_POST['firstname'] . '-' . $_POST['email'] . "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('/tmp/mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
```

but I get permission denied. I changed the permissions to 777, but it still didn't work.

I need help to post it. I don't care what command you use, just for it to post the name and email.

Comment: We try to discourage "send me the full code" posts here, as they are considered a form of [help vampirism](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/). Consider answers below as help to get you on your way, rather than people being keen to work for free.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you have access to the `/tmp` directory on the server. You probably have your own `tmp` directory and are just using the wrong path.

If that directory is inside the same directory this script is running this should work:

```
$ret = file_put_contents('./tmp/mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Notice the `.` before `/tmp` which means that file path starts in the same directory as this file.